# Refactor Haskell monadic code to avoid copy-paste

Tags: haskell, st-monad

I have written the following code in Haskell using ST monad and it works. My only question is how do I avoid the copy-paste shown in the code below. When I tried to refactor the code, I got compiler errors I could not fully understand. Is there a way to avoid the copy-paste in the code below. I would like to know, if I could refactor the code that processes for start_1 and start_2 (as of now copy/paste) to another helper function.

```
import qualified Control.Monad as CM
import qualified Control.Monad.ST as CMST
import qualified Data.Array as A
import qualified Data.Array.Unboxed as AU
import qualified Data.Array.ST as AST


prime_factors :: Int -> Int -> [(Int, Int)] -> A.Array Int [(Int, Int)]
prime_factors a_low a_high prms_sqrts = AST.runSTArray $ do
  pfs <- AST.newArray (a_low, a_high) [] :: CMST.ST s (AST.STArray s Int [(Int, Int)])
  as <- AST.newArray (a_low, a_high) 0 :: CMST.ST s (AST.STArray s Int Int)
  CM.forM_ [a_low..a_high] $ \i -> do
    AST.writeArray as i ((i * i) + 1)
  CM.forM_ (takeWhile (\(prm, _) -> prm <= (a_high + 1)) prms_sqrts) $ \(prm, sqr_rt) -> do
    let (q, r) = a_low `divMod` prm
    let start_1 = a_low + sqr_rt - r
    -- !!!! CODE TO DO SOME PROCESSING FOR start_1 !!!!!
    CM.forM_ (takeWhile (<= a_high) [start_1 + (x * prm) | x <- [0..]]) $ \i -> do
      a_i <- AST.readArray as i
      let (a_i', mul) = remove_factor a_i prm 0
      CM.when (mul > 0) $ do
        AST.writeArray as i a_i'
        pfs_i <- AST.readArray pfs i
        AST.writeArray pfs i ((prm, mul) : pfs_i)
    let start_2 = a_low + (prm - sqr_rt) - r
    -- !!!! COPY-PASTE ABOVE CODE TO PROCESS start_2 !!!!
    CM.forM_ (takeWhile (<= a_high) [start_2 + (x * prm) | x <- [0..]]) $ \i -> do
      a_i <- AST.readArray as i
      let (a_i', mul) = remove_factor a_i prm 0
      CM.when (mul > 0) $ do
        AST.writeArray as i a_i'
        pfs_i <- AST.readArray pfs i
        AST.writeArray pfs i ((prm, mul) : pfs_i)
  CM.forM_ [a_low..a_high] $ \i -> do
    a_i <- AST.readArray as i
    CM.when (a_i > 1) $ do
      pfs_i <- AST.readArray pfs i
      AST.writeArray pfs i ((a_i, 1) : pfs_i)
  return pfs
  where remove_factor m p mul
          | m `mod` p == 0 = remove_factor (m `div` p) p (mul + 1)
          | otherwise = (m, mul)
```

The error message I get when I try to move the above copy-paste code to a local function (named sieve_factors) created with a 'let' binding is:

```
vamsi@vamsi-laptop:~/learn/project_euler/129_to_256/problem_224$ ghc --make -O -i../.. problem_224.hs
[3 of 3] Compiling Main             ( problem_224.hs, problem_224.o )

problem_224.hs:39:9: error:
    • Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: AST.MArray (AST.STArray s) Int m
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        sieve_factors :: forall (m :: * -> *).
                         (AST.MArray (AST.STArray s) Int m,
                          AST.MArray (AST.STArray s) [(Int, Int)] m) =>
                         Int -> m ()
      In the expression:
        do { let sieve_factors start = ...;
             let (q, r) = a_low `divMod` prm;
             let start_1 = a_low + sqr_rt - r;
             sieve_factors start_1;
             .... }
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘\ (prm, sqr_rt)
           -> do { let ...;
                   let ...;
                   .... }’
```

Comment: What kind of refactoring are you interested? What error messages do you got from GHC?

Comment: Please always add relevant import statements to a question.

Comment: @RodrigoRibeiro I want to take the code that processes start_1 and start_2 as highlighted in the above code and move it to a different function, which I can simply call twice.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Added imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler tells you to

> ```
> Use FlexibleContexts to permit this
> ```

That means enable the [`FlexibleContexts` language extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.2/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#relaxed-rules-for-instance-contexts). You can do this by adding a [`LANGUAGE` pragma](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.2/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#language-pragma) to the top of your source file

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
```

Comment: Thanks, adding that fixed the issue. But, I would rather not use a language feature I do not fully understand, so I am leaving the copy-paste as is, I do not understand why regular Haskell without any extensions allow me to refactor some copy-paste code to a different function.

Comment: At this point in time worrying about writing Haskell 98 code (as in 1998) is nearly senseless. GHC is now the defacto standard for Haskell. `FlexibleContexts`, `FlexibleInstances`, and `MultiParamTypeClasses` should be part of the language spec. You're already using `MultiParamTypeClasses` via `Data.Array` because the type class `MArray` has multiple parameters. You're already using `FlexibleInstances` because the `MArray` instance for `STArray` requires it. Needing `FlexibleContexts` is an inevitable consequence of using `FlexibleInstances`. They just hadn't shown up in your code yet.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am not too familiar with FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances and MultiParamTypeClasses. I will try to learn about them. Also, don't we have a standard of Haskell after 1998 i.e. Haskell 2010? Based on this link, [Haskell 2010](https://wiki.haskell.org/Haskell_2010) the features you mentioned are not in Haskell 2010 either.